# Determining ideals, isomorphic rings of $\Bbb C[x, y]/(y^2 - x^3)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

I've been having a substantial amount of trouble trying to understand the workings of $\Bbb C[x, y]$ mod... anything really. I figure this particular example is a good one to ask here because I probably understand it the least.

As I guiding problem, I'd like to understand what $\Bbb C[x, y]/(y^2 - x^3)$ is isomorphic to and why, but also what $\Bbb C[x, y]/(y^2 - x^3)$ mod the ideal generated by the coset of x is isomorphic to.

The first time I encountered this type of ring it was introduced with long division and some business about a function sending things to t. I hope this vague and clearly confused description paints a picture how how little I understand about this. For the second problem above, I tried to circumvent this by saying the following, where $x`$ is the coset of $x$ in $\Bbb C[x, y]/(y^2 - x^3)$:

$(\Bbb C[x, y]/(y^2 - x^3))/(x`)$ is equivalent to $(\Bbb C[x, y]/(y^2 - x^3))/((x)/(y^2 - x^3))$ -is this even true?

And then by the Third Isomorphism Theorem

$(\Bbb C[x, y]/(y^2 - x^3))/((x)/(y^2 - x^3))$ $\cong$ $\Bbb C[x, y]/(x)$

I feel like there's no way this is correct, but also I understand it so little that I can't even be sure of that.

What's with the $t$, $\Bbb C[t]$, $\Bbb C[t^2, t^3]$ stuff? It seems necessary to working with this but I've yet to encounter a clear description of what's going on with it. And there are also things using $f(x, y) = g(x, y)(y^2-x^3) + h(y)$ by long division... how does knowing this help?

Comment: The application of _Third Isomorphism Theorem_ is correct; and the quotient ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[y]$.

Answer (score 2):

For the last part of your question, you have a $\mathbf C$-algebra homomorphism
\begin{align}
\mathbf C[x,y]&\longrightarrow \mathbf C[t]\\
x & \longmapsto t^2,\\
y & \longmapsto t^3
\end{align}
The kernel is the prime ideal generated by $y^2-x^3$. The maximal ideals of $\mathbf C[x,y]$, by the *Nullstellensatz*, have the form $(x-\alpha, y-\beta)$. Those which contain the kernel satisfy the equation $\;\beta^2-\alpha^3=0$, and the above homomorphism corresponds to a parametrisation of the cubic curve with equation $y^2-x^3=0$, obtained by determining the non-trivial intersections of the curve with the lines $y=tx$.